# Is it possible to Outline a view port in threejs?

Tags: three.js, rendering, viewport, outline

I've created a scene with two cameras and one renderer. each camera is looking at the scene from a different angle and I have the first camera rendering on the entire screen then the second camera I have rendering in a small view port laying on top of the first render. I was wondering if there is a way to have that second view port outlined so that each look separate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can outline an inset viewport by rendering a solid-colored rectangle slightly larger than the inset prior to rendering the inset.

```
// border
renderer.setScissorTest( true );
renderer.setScissor( x, y, width, height );
renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 1 ); // border color
renderer.clearColor(); // clear color buffer
```

Then, render the inset. Just make sure the inset background is opaque.

three.js r.86

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using threejs viewport feature? As far as I know, by itself, it does not have such a feature.

But since it is rendered on to canvas... maybe you could draw an outline by yourself on canvas in desired coordinates, after each threejs render frame?

A basic example:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(20,20,150,100);
ctx.stroke();
```

(reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_rect.asp)

Comment: Up-voting this because it's likely the simplest way to accomplish the desired effect without polluting the scene(s) and doing other rendering trickery. That said, you can't get a 2D context off a canvas which has already given a 3D context. You'd need to grab the image from the 3D canvas and draw it to a 2D canvas, _then_ draw the outline lines.

Comment: Calling `getContext("2d")` returns `null`.